# program isn't calculating right, 3D transformation problems

Tags: c++, c++11, graphics, 3d

Hi I have created a model to device method for my 3D transformation lab in C++
I have narrowed down my issue to my model to device 3d method, it is doing something really weird.
I have a screen shot i will attach, but the problem will be obvious. it is coming out to be NAN.

Here is the code

```
matrix viewContext::model_to_device_3D(const matrix& param) {
matrix hold_values(param); //copy
double temp = 0;
//TODO [0][2] OR [2][0]
hold_values[0][2] = 1;
std::cout << std::endl << "hold values" << hold_values << std::endl;
hold_values = (M3D * hold_values);

//may have to do 1/hold_values[3][0] then multiply that with hold_values
temp = (1 / (hold_values[2][0]));
std::cout << "temp value" << temp << std::endl;

hold_values = hold_values * temp;
std::cout << "hold values return value " << hold_values << std::endl;

return hold_values;
```

}

as well as the shape that is calling it, triangle.

```
    // Draw triangle.

void triangle::draw(GraphicsContext* gcontext, viewContext* vContext) {
    static int tester = 1;

    matrix temp(4, 1);
    matrix temp2(4, 1);
    matrix temp3(4, 1);

    temp[0][0] = origin[0][0];
    temp[1][0] = origin[1][0];
    temp[2][0] = origin[2][0];
    temp[3][0] = 1;
    temp2[0][0] = origin[0][1];
    temp2[1][0] = origin[1][1];
    temp2[2][0] = origin[2][1];
    temp2[3][0] = 1;
    temp3[0][0] = origin[0][2];
    temp3[1][0] = origin[1][2];
    temp3[2][0] = origin[2][2];
    temp3[3][0] = 1;

    std::cout << "temp1 " << temp << std::endl;

//  temp = vContext->model_to_device_3D(temp);
//  temp2 = vContext->model_to_device_3D(temp2);
//  temp3 = vContext->model_to_device_3D(temp3);

    temp = vContext->model_to_device_3D(temp);
    temp2 = vContext->model_to_device_3D(temp2);
    temp3 = vContext->model_to_device_3D(temp3);

    std::cout << "temp 1" << temp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "temp 2" << temp2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "temp 3" << temp3 << std::endl;

    //set color to color input from constructor.
    gcontext->setColor(color);
    //x1,y1,x2,y2
    gcontext->drawLine(temp[0][0], temp[1][0], temp2[0][0], temp2[1][0]);
    //x2,y2,x3,y3
    gcontext->drawLine(temp2[0][0], temp2[1][0], temp3[0][0], temp3[1][0]);
    //x3,y3,x1,y1
    gcontext->drawLine(temp3[0][0], temp3[1][0], temp[0][0], temp[1][0]);

    //std::cout << "just drew a triangle" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "triangle draw # " << tester << std::endl;
    sleep(3);
    tester++;
}
```

I just don't seem to know what is going wrong with this. please help.
[Picture of what is wrong!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX3x8.jpg)

This is what i am getting during compilation, like it compiles fine but i get this. it seems that double temp is getting infinity which is ruining everything else?

Comment: `hold_values[2][0]` is zero. It's a pretty odd coordinate to divide by; `hold_values[3][0]` would be more expected. (From your comments, it seems that you're not certain what the computation should be, so you should probably work that out first.)

Comment: @molbdnilo it goes [x,y,z,1] and I want to divide by the z component which would be [2][0] since it starts at [0][0]
that is what I learned in computer graphics atleast, unless there is something i am missing from here.

Comment: @molbdnilo hey sorry i get what you're saying, i believe it is [3][0]